# How to filter out draft messages from gmail api history.list

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

When I use history.list, it returns messages with labelId "DRAFT" which I do not need to retrieve.

So I did this to retrieve messages only with labelId "INBOX":

> history =
>   service.users().history().list(userId='me',startHistoryId=1234567,
>   labelId="INBOX", maxResults=5).execute()

But I still got "DRAFT" messages:

> {'id': '1234567', 'messages': [{'id': '1234efe91cbd1234', 'threadId':
>   '1234e68cb9951234'}], 'messagesAdded': [{'message': {'id':
>   '1234efe91cbd1234', 'threadId': '1234e68cb9951234', 'labelIds':
>   ['DRAFT']}}]}

I must do something grossly wrong. 
Could someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible you are getting the history for messages *currently* in INBOX?  That may have previously been in DRAFT?

Comment: @that is not the case. Is there any reliable way to get INBOX only messages?

Comment: One thing I've noticed in the documentation of [Users.history: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list) that there are only 4 `historyTypes`, namely "labelAdded", "labelRemoved", "messageAdded" and "messageDeleted". it is not specified if from drafts or inbox.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 historyTypes are different from labelId. But I also tried historyTypes and got "Invalid label value in query"